# Angular 4 File Upload Form Validation

Tags: javascript, forms, angular

I have the problem with angular form validation.

This is my form-component.ts code:

```
     <!-- language: lang-type-script -->
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
    import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

   ** Image Converter Base64  
      public base64textString: String = "";
      handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var files = evt.target.files;
        var file = files[0];

        if (files && file) {
          var reader = new FileReader();

          reader.onload = this._handleReaderLoaded.bind(this);

          reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
        }
      }

      _handleReaderLoaded(readerEvt) {
        this.base64textString = btoa(readerEvt.target.result);
      }

    ** Form Validation
    ...
    photo = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
    ...
    ** Form Group
    internFormStep1: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
        ...
        photo: this.base64textString
    });
```

This is my form-component.html code:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
    <form [formGroup]="internFormStep1">
     <div class="row">
              <fieldset class="form-group col-6 pull-left" [ngClass]="{'has-danger': internFormStep1.get('photo').hasError('required') && internFormStep1.get('photo').touched}">
                <label for="photo" class="form-control-label">
          Fotoğraf
        </label><br>

                <label class="btn btn-secondary" for="filePicker">
            <input type="file" id="filePicker" style="display:none;"  (change)="handleFileSelect($event)" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/bmp" class="custom-file-input" [formControl]="internFormStep1.get('photo')"
              [ngClass]="{'form-control-danger': internFormStep1.get('photo').hasError('required') && internFormStep1.get('photo').touched}">
              Yükle
        </label>
                <div class="form-control-feedback" *ngIf="internFormStep1.get('photo').hasError('required') && internFormStep1.get('photo').touched">Fotoğraf gerekli</div>
              </fieldset>
              <div class="form-group col-6 pull-left avatar-lg">
                <div *ngIf="base64textString"><img class="img-fluid" src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{base64textString}}" /></div>
              </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

I convert the image from the form to base64 format. But the form does not accept it. How can I solve this?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what is going wrong? Are you getting an error?

Comment: I do not get any errors, just verification.

Answer (score 0):

You can put "data:image/png;base64," all along with image data together.

inside you template, try

```
<img class="img-fluid" [src]="base64textString" />
```

inside controller, try something like this:

```
base64textString = "data:image/png;base64,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";
```

Comment: That's not my problem. FormControl does not see the value of the image from the form or sees the value entered as not entered.